# Filter records in a component using a search term from another component on Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a Component called **task-board** where I have the following table:

```
<tr *ngFor="let task of tasks | taskFilter: searchText" >
<td>{{ task.taskName }}</td>
<td>{{ task.location }}</td>
<td>{{ task.description }}</td>
<td>{{ task.timeElapsed }}</td>
<td>{{ task.completed }}</td>
</tr>
```

Also, I have a Component called **task-search** that has the code below:

```
<label>Search:</label>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText" />
<p>You are looking for: {{ searchText }}</p>
```

And a Pipe named **taskFilter** with this code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'taskFilter'
})
export class TaskFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
  if(!items) return [];
  if(!searchText) return items;
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
     return items.filter( it => {
  return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
   });
 }
}
```

My goal is to filter the itens from **task-board** using the value from the input on **task-search**.

At the moment even if I write something it does not filter.

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one of the components could be made a child of the other, you could bind/emit the input from the search with `@Input()`, `@Output` and `EventEmitter`. Something like this:

**Inside task-board template:**

```
<task-search (searchValueChanged)="updateFilter($event)"></task-search>
```

**Inside task-board code:**

```
updateFilter(searchText: string): void {
  this.searchText = searchText;
}
```

**Inside task-search template:**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText" (change)="changedSearchText()" />
```

**Inside task-search code:**

```
// ... imports ...
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'
// ... inside the class ...
@Output() searchValueChanged: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

changedSearchText(): void {
  // emit the change so the parent component can see it
  this.searchValueChanged.emit(this.searchText);
}
```

Check out the documentation here for more info: [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check the code of your filter, but first you need a binding between task-board and task-search in order to pass searchText. So try this :

```
// task-board.component.ts
@Input() searchText;

// task-search.component.html
<task-board [searchText]="searchText"></task-board>
```

If you don't want to do direct bindings between task-board and task-search, you can also create a service to perform this